# The argument type 'List<MaterialAccentColor>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'MaterialColor'

Tags: flutter, dart

Why can't I set the `accents` as  a color?

This is my code :

```
Text('Hello',
     style: TextStyle(color: Colors.accents),
     )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reality accents is not a `color` but rather a `list`(*const List accents*) that contains a lot of `colors` (accent colors).
Its implementation is  :

```
static const List<MaterialAccentColor> accents = <MaterialAccentColor>[
  redAccent,
  pinkAccent,
  purpleAccent,
  deepPurpleAccent,
  indigoAccent,
  blueAccent,
  lightBlueAccent,
  cyanAccent,
  tealAccent,
  greenAccent,
  lightGreenAccent,
  limeAccent,
  yellowAccent,
  amberAccent,
  orangeAccent,
  deepOrangeAccent,
]
```

You can find it on the flutter website via this [link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Colors/accents-constant.html)

Now that we know it's a `list`, to retrieve one of its elements, just do `List_name[element_index]`. So in our case we'll do `accents [color_index]`.
A small example of use :

```
Text('Hello',
     style: TextStyle(color: Colors.accents[0]),
     ),
```

Colors.accents[0] for `redAccent`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hi @martiX4 i found that you are passing invalid type to TextStyle widget now as answer given by @abhishek you can use index accents[index] based on your condition

for example if you use redAccent then you can use

```
List<MaterialAccentColor> accents = <MaterialAccentColor>[
redAccent,blueAccent]; 

// accents[0] => for redAccent
// accents[0] => for blueAccent

Text('Hello', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.accents[0]),)
```

Answer (score 0):

accents is List so you can't be assigned to the `color`

```
 /// The material design accent color swatches.
  static const List<MaterialAccentColor> accents = <MaterialAccentColor>[
    redAccent,
    pinkAccent,
    purpleAccent,
    deepPurpleAccent,
    indigoAccent,
    blueAccent,
    lightBlueAccent,
    cyanAccent,
    tealAccent,
    greenAccent,
    lightGreenAccent,
    limeAccent,
    yellowAccent,
    amberAccent,
    orangeAccent,
    deepOrangeAccent,
  ];
```

you can use `accents` color using index value

```
Text('Hello',
     style: TextStyle(color: Colors.accents[0]),
     )
```